# Grunt - Fatal error undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs

I am trying to use npm module `node-version-assets` in `grunt`. My grunt file looks like below:

```js
module.exports = function(grunt){
    grunt.registerTask('version-assets', 'version the static assets just created', function() {

        var Version = require("node-version-assets");
        var versionInstance = new Version({
            assets: ['public/dboard/css/style.css', 'public/dboard/js/doc-load.js'],
            grepFiles: ['views/dashboard.jade']
        });

        var cb = this.async();
        versionInstance.run(cb);
    });

    grunt.registerTask('default', 'version-assets');
};
```

But I keep getting this error:

> Running "version-assets" task
>   Fatal error: undefined is not a function

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that you have installed `version-assets`. Have you already run `npm install`? Is `version-assets` in your package.json file?

Make sure of those two things, and then if it still does not work, run grunt in verbose mode:

```
grunt --verbose
```

And update your question with the output.